# Condição if para não mostrar imagens que não existe PHP

Tags: php

```
<fieldset>
                    <legend>FOTOS</legend>  
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <?php
                                if ($linha['foto1_bci'] && $linha['foto2_bci'] && $linha['foto3_bci'] && $linha['foto4_bci'] && $linha['foto5_bci']) { ?>
                                    <label for="foto1_bci">Foto 1</label>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="fotos/<?=$linha['foto1_bci']?>" width="500px" height="200px"></img>

                                    <label for="foto2_bci">Foto 2</label>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="fotos/<?=$linha['foto2_bci']?>" width="500px" height="200px"></img>

                                    <label for="foto3_bci">Foto 3</label>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="fotos/<?=$linha['foto3_bci']?>" width="500px" height="200px"></img>

                                    <label for="foto4_bci">Foto 4</label>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="fotos/<?=$linha['foto4_bci']?>" width="500px" height="200px"></img>

                                    <label for="foto5_bci">Foto 5</label>
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src="fotos/<?=$linha['foto5_bci']?>" width="500px" height="200px"></img>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                </fieldset>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Como posso mostrar apenas as imagens que existem? Porque só fiz upload da imagem 1 porém mostra um icone como se não exibisse e o nome Foto2 Foto3 Foto4, eu gostaria de não fosse exibido se a imagem não existisse.

Answer (score 1):

Emmanuel, você pode melhorar realizando um for e verificando se o item é diferente de nada.

```
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
   if(isset($linha['foto'.$i.'bci']) && $linha['foto'.$i.'bci'] != '') { ?>
       <label for="<?='foto'.$i.'bci'?>">Foto <?=$i?></label>
       <img class="img-responsive" src="fotos/<?=$linha['foto'.$i.'bci']?>" width="500px" height="200px"></img>
   <?php
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Comentei o código para melhor entendimento, é melhor você usar um foreach por ser melhor na questão de evitar retrabalho caso você precise colocar uma foto a mais ou retirar, o for é algo manual onde você seta as posições, com foreach você vai rodar todas as posições independentes de quantas tenha.

```
<?php
// Iniciando contador
$i = 0;
// Rodando todas as posições
foreach ($linha as $key => $foto) {
    // Verificando se a foto é nula ou vazia
    if($foto != '' && $foto != null) { ?>
    <!-- Montando a label e a imagem -->
    <label for=<?php 'foto'.$i.'_bci' ?>>Foto <?php $i ?></label>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="fotos/<?php echo $foto ?>"></img>
<?php
    }
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá @Emmanuel,

Vc tem um campo para cada foto no banco de dados isso?
Então vc salva o nome da imagem em cada um deles.

- Uma alternativa seria salvar o nome das imagens em um unico campo, e realizar o foreach para leitura.
- Caso vc queira manter em campos separados como está fazendo atualmente, pode fazer o seguinte para que mostre somente as imagens existentes, verificando os campos do bd preenchidos e os vazios:

  ```
  $sql = "SELECT imagem1,imagem2,imagem3 FROM table";
  ```

  $rs_sql = mysqli_query($conex,$sql);

  ```
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs_sql)) {
         $imagem1 = $row['imagem1'];
         $imagem2 = $row['imagem2'];
         $imagem3 = $row['imagem3'];
  }

  $imagens = "$imagem1,$imagem2,$imagem3";
  $imagens = explode(",",$imagens);

  foreach($imagens as $imgs){             

              if($imgs!=""){

                  $imgs_src []= "         
                      <img src='$imgs' width='150px' height='150px' />        
                  ";  

              }//end if   

      }//end foreach



      echo join($imgs_src);
  ```